# ER Diagram Design

Tags: database, datetime, primary-key, entity-relationship, composite-primary-key

I would like clarify if I can have 2 tables whose primary keys are the same set of composite keys.

For example:

```
Lesson[tID, sID, dateTime, duration, testGiven]

Test[tID,sID,dateTime,studentScore]
```

Notice the primary keys of both tables are the same, but each table serves a different purpose. Will there be problems with a design like this? Or is it good?

Also, I am having a dateTime stamp as part of the primary key, is this recommended/discouraged?

Comment: Joining the tables together will be require matching all three columns. Would work but I wouldn't do it that way. Also matching a DT is not good idea unless it based on an integer.

Comment: What would be a better way swdev?

Comment: Usually you want single primary key column in each table unless you have a good reason not to. In your case I don't see a good reason.